# How to implement a dynamic referral program?

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

Example: Currently, we will provide 100 credits each to both the referrer and referred.

Then in the future, we might want to implement a different referral program. Such as change credits to 200 instead of 100.

Then again in the future, give each 100 credits as well give referrer 50 if the referred spends 100 with us for the first time.

Then again in the future, give each 100 credits as well give referrer 50 each time the referred spends 100 with us.

Also, sometimes restrict the program to a few users only.

"**Dynamic referral**": We should be able to create different referral programs in the long course. Should be dynamic and able to take stats from the data.

Is it OK to change the database every time we come up with a new referral program?

I'm confused. How to create a schema/design/table(model) for such? Please help.

---

**Note:** I didn't include any design attempt because I couldn't think of it. I'm confused. I want it to be generic. I could build models for different referral programs. But I'm looking for something more generic. Is it even possible? I wonder.

Comment: How is it currently designed? 
Im thinking this is just some stored procedure somewhere running over a table somewhere, then updating a person's account somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Separate data and business logic.

A database is a repository for data, so put those numbers in a table (let's call it `Creds`), possibly with date ranges of when they are applicable.

Your application code is where you build the "business logic" that interprets "referrer", "referree", "first time", etc, based on the data.

For example "first time" would come from some *other* table that, for example, has the entire list of "referred spends" for a user.  You would write a suitable query to determine "first time", then use `Creds` to and the current date to decide how much credit to give a user.

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts: Don't store the credit points, just store the referrals with the rule that is currently active for that referral.

This way the credits for any given time can be calculated and recalculated. It also makes it easier to report on "what if" simulations to see how different peoples credits would have been if other rules where in action at any given time.

Or store credits if needed, but just as a cache that should be  recalculated when needed, maybe changed through triggers on insert to the referral table and the spending table (for when someone reaches minimum spending for kickbacks to kick in). You might also be able to calculate the credits through a database VIEW.

```
create table rule (
  ruleid,
  rule_valid_from_time,
  rule_valid_to_time,
  credit_referrer number,
  credit_referred number,
  credit_kickback_to_referrer number,
  credit_kickback_referred_spend_minimum number,
  constraint pk_rule primary key (ruleid)
);
insert into rule ('RuleA','2019-01-01T00:00:00','2019-02-12T23:59:59',100,100,null,null);
insert into rule ('RuleB','2019-02-13T00:00:00','2019-03-31T23:59:59',50,100,100,200);

create table referral (
  userid_referrer,
  usedid_referred,
  time,
  ruleid,
  constraint pk_referral primary key (userid_referrer, userid_referred)
);
insert into referral ('Alice', 'Bob', '2019-02-12T21:01:22','RuleA');
insert into referral ('Bob',   'Eve', '2019-02-14T10:30:01','RuleB');
```

Comment: The `T` in a `DATETIME` won't work.